# Convert a list of "dictionary of dictionaries" to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of "dictionary of dictionaries" that looks like this:

```
lis = [{'Health and Welfare Plan + Change Notification': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'null',
   'latest_test_result_date': 'null',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
   'test_result': 'null'}},
 {'Health and Welfare Plan + Computations': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'null',
   'latest_test_result_date': 'null',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
   'test_result': 'null'}},
 {'Health and Welfare Plan + Data Agreements': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'Due to the Policy',
   'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
   'test_result': 'null'}},
 {'Health and Welfare Plan + Data Elements': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
   'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
   'test_result': 'null'}},
 {'Health and Welfare Plan + Data Quality Monitoring': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'xxx',
   'latest_test_result_date': '2019-08-09',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
   'test_result': 'xxx'}},
 {'Health and Welfare Plan + HPU Source Reliability': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'xxx.',
   'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
   'test_result': 'null'}},
 {'Health and Welfare Plan + Lineage': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'null',
   'latest_test_result_date': 'null',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'Not Started',
   'test_result': 'null'}},
 {'Health and Welfare Plan + Metadata': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'Valid',
   'latest_test_result_date': '2020-07-02',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'Completed',
   'test_result': 'xxx'}},
 {'Health and Welfare Plan + Usage Reconciliation': {'evidence_capture': 'null',
   'test_result_justification': 'Test out of scope',
   'latest_test_result_date': '2019-10-02',
   'last_updated_by': 'null',
   'test_execution_status': 'In Progress',
   'test_result': 'null'}}]
```

I would like to convert the list into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                        evidence_capture last_updated_by latest_test_result_date test_execution_status test_result test_result_justification            test_category
Change Notification                 null            null                    null           Not Started        null                      null  Health and Welfare Plan
Computations                        null            null                    null           Not Started        null                      null  Health and Welfare Plan
Data Agreements                     null            null              2019-10-02           In Progress        null         Due to the Policy  Health and Welfare Plan
Data Elements                       null            null              2019-10-02           In Progress        null                       xxx  Health and Welfare Plan
Data Quality Monitoring             null            null              2019-08-09             Completed         xxx                       xxx  Health and Welfare Plan
HPU Source Reliability              null            null              2019-10-02           In Progress        null                      xxx.  Health and Welfare Plan
Lineage                             null            null                    null           Not Started        null                      null  Health and Welfare Plan
Metadata                            null            null              2020-07-02             Completed         xxx                     Valid  Health and Welfare Plan
Usage Reconciliation                null            null              2019-10-02           In Progress        null         Test out of scope  Health and Welfare Plan
```

My code to build the dataframe is using a for-loop to concat the records column by column. After that to process the column names, and then transpose it. The final output would have the repeated string "Health and Welfare Plan" removed from each row index, but appended as a new column.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(lis[0])
for i in range(1, len(lis)):
    df3 = pd.concat([df3, pd.DataFrame(lis[i])], axis=1)
df3.columns = [col.split(' + ')[1] for col in df3.columns]
df3 = df3.T
df3['test_category'] = 'Health and Welfare Plan'
print(df3)
```

The code is able to produce the final output, but using "expensive" functions of both for-loop and dataframe concat. So I was wondering if there is a better way to output the same results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us do dict comp to flatten the list of dictionaries

```
pd.DataFrame({k.split(' + ')[1]: v for d in lis for k, v in d.items()}).T
```

---

```
                        evidence_capture test_result_justification latest_test_result_date last_updated_by test_execution_status test_result
Change Notification                 null                      null                    null            null           Not Started        null
Computations                        null                      null                    null            null           Not Started        null
Data Agreements                     null         Due to the Policy              2019-10-02            null           In Progress        null
Data Elements                       null                       xxx              2019-10-02            null           In Progress        null
Data Quality Monitoring             null                       xxx              2019-08-09            null             Completed         xxx
HPU Source Reliability              null                      xxx.              2019-10-02            null           In Progress        null
Lineage                             null                      null                    null            null           Not Started        null
Metadata                            null                     Valid              2020-07-02            null             Completed         xxx
Usage Reconciliation                null         Test out of scope              2019-10-02            null           In Progress        null
```

Answer (score 4):

You can build your dataframe out of the dictionary values and set the index manually by splitting by '+':

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(e.values())[0] for e in lis])
df.index = map(lambda x: x.split('+')[-1].strip(), [list(e.keys())[0] for e in lis])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                        evidence_capture test_result_justification  ... test_execution_status test_result
Change Notification                 null                      null  ...           Not Started        null
Computations                        null                      null  ...           Not Started        null
Data Agreements                     null         Due to the Policy  ...           In Progress        null
Data Elements                       null                       xxx  ...           In Progress        null
Data Quality Monitoring             null                       xxx  ...             Completed         xxx
HPU Source Reliability              null                      xxx.  ...           In Progress        null
Lineage                             null                      null  ...           Not Started        null
Metadata                            null                     Valid  ...             Completed         xxx
Usage Reconciliation                null         Test out of scope  ...           In Progress        null

[9 rows x 6 columns]
```

Edit: it might be faster to do it all in one loop:

```
data = []
ind = []
for e in lis:
    data.append(list(e.values())[0])
    ind.append(list(e.keys())[0].split('+')[1].strip())
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ind)
```

You can still add your new column at the end with `df['test_category'] = 'Health and Welfare Plan'`

Comment: sorry, I also need to add a new column `df['test_category'] = 'Health and Welfare Plan'` is it possible?

Comment: I updated my answer. I would simply add your test column after creating df

Answer (score 3):

I have modified part of your code to get the same results. Using dictionary manipulation should be faster

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {}
for e in lis:
    dic[list(e.keys())[0]] = list(e.values())[0]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df3.columns = [col.split('+')[-1].strip() for col in df3.columns]
df3 = df3.T
df3['test_category'] = 'Health and Welfare Plan'
print(df3)
```